# Time Widgets or Static Blocks

Tags: static-block, widgets

Is it possible to set a start/end date for Static Blocks or Widgets somehow?

Or is this only possible with Banners?

I know it would be possible to do this using CMS layout for specific pages or categories, but I am planning on doing a sitewide implementation of a static block/widget and was wondering if there is a possibility to give these a specfic date when they show up/stop showing up.

So basically I would like to create a static block and show Date from Date1 to Date2 and after that date hide it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box.

When you're creating a custom widget you could add 2 date fields and use those in the `_toHtml()` method to either show or suppress output which would probably be the easiest solution.

For static blocks etc you would need to add *date from* and *to* columns to the database extending the blocks that display these elements to check for the date being valid.

It would involve quite a lot of rewriting so probably only use it if you really have to

Comment: static block is the entity where Magento uses least number of specific event dispatches. You are absolutely right on the "rewrite" statement. It deserves a +1

Comment: I had this on my screen before and wasn´t sure if thats the easiest but it seems like its not that difficult to do it that way so I will give it a try. Thanks a lot